# How to delete a specific line when it equals a certain text?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which is put into the Index Worksheet I have in my workbook.  It creates a hyperlink to each worksheet on my "Index" tab and should create a hyperlink in Cell "A1" called Back to Index.  It's working perfectly fine however if I ever add a new worksheet I have to go through tab by tab and delete the first line, I've looked into the issue and haven't been able to come up with anything to resolve the issue.

In short I want to delete Row 1 on each worksheet that contains the text "Back to Index" in cell "A1".  Would anyone have any suggestions on this?  Thank you very much for anyone who can offer advice on the issue.

```
Sub TCIndex()
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim l As Long
Dim lastRow As Long


l = 1

With Me
    .Columns(1).ClearContents
    .Cells(1, 1) = "INDEX"
    .Cells(1, 1).Name = "Index"
    .Rows(1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Rows(1).Font.Size = 14
    .Rows(1).RowHeight = 18
    .Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 60
    .Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Range("A1").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    .Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
    .Range("A1:A1").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Range("A2:A70").RowHeight = 15
    .Range("A2:A70").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For Each Cell In Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    If Cell.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    Else
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
Next Cell


For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    If wSheet.Name <> Me.Name Then
        l = l + 1
        With wSheet
            .Range("A1").Name = "Start_" & wSheet.Index
            .Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A1"), Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="Index", TextToDisplay:="Back to Index"
        End With
        Me.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Me.Cells(l, 1), Address:="", _
    SubAddress:="Start_" & wSheet.Index, TextToDisplay:=wSheet.Name
    End If
Next wSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to show your code that you've attempted and where it has failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question
**I want to delete Row 1 on each worksheet that contains the text "Back to Index" in cell "A1".**

```
for each wrkSht in worksheets
    if wrkSht.[A1] = "Back to Index" then
        wrkSht.rows(1).delete
    endif
next wrkSht
```